# How to make div reverse the animation on button toggle using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

The following code makes my div slide from right to left in my screen. I want to reverse the animation on second button click . But this simply makes my div disappear and appear instantaneously without any animation.Function slider3 is my failed attempt at reversing the animation. The login box right margin is initially -570px .

```js
function call_slider() {

  setTimeout("slider()", 50)
}

function slider() {

  var label = document.getElementById("container1");
  if (label.style.display == 'block') {

    alert('this Element is block');
    document.getElementById("login_box").style.right = "-570px";
    label.style.display = "none";
  } else {

    alert('this Element is hidden');

    setInterval(slider2, 10);
    label.style.display = "block";
  }

}


function slider2() {

  if (document.getElementById("login_box").style.right != "10px") {
    document.getElementById("login_box").style.right = parseInt(document.getElementById("login_box").style.right || 0) + 10 + 'px';

  }
}

function slider3() {

  if (document.getElementById("login_box").style.left != "-570px") {
    document.getElementById("login_box").style.left = parseInt(document.getElementById("login_box").style.left || 0) + 10 + 'px';

  }

}
```

```css
.login-box {
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1" id="container1" style="height:900px;position:absolute; z-index: 1;">


  <form method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="mySubmit() " style="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="login-box" id="login_box" style=" right:-570px;">

    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: post your full code (html + css)

Comment: I just did, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes are commented in your code

```js
function call_slider() {

  setTimeout("slider()", 50)
}

function slider() {


  var label = document.getElementById("container1");
  if (label.style.display == 'block') {

    alert('this Element is block');
    //replaced your code with slider 3 function
    
    
    //assign interval function as a proprty of global window so it can be accessed by another function
    window.moveRight = setInterval(slider3, 10);
    
  } else {

    alert('this Element is hidden');

    //make your element visible before start animation
    label.style.display = "block";

     window.moveLeft = setInterval(slider2, 10);
    
  }

}


function slider2() {
  
  //parse the right property as integer 
  var right = parseInt(document.getElementById("login_box").style.right,10)

  if ( right < 10) {
    document.getElementById("login_box").style.right = right + 10 + 'px';

  } else {
  
      //important -- cancel the interval after animation finished else it will run infinitely and interfere with other other functions
      clearInterval(window.moveLeft)
  }
  
}

function slider3() {

  //user right here instead of left
  //use the same property in other animation
  var right = parseInt(document.getElementById("login_box").style.right,10)

  if ( right > -570) {
    document.getElementById("login_box").style.right = right - 10 + 'px';

  } else {
  
    // This is where you get stuck
    // in your code the container element is hidden before animation is performed therefore you didn't see box moving to right
    
    
    //hide container1 element only after entire login-box  is moved to right
  
      var label = document.getElementById("container1").style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(window.moveRight)
  }
}
```

```css
.login-box{

      width:320px;
      position: absolute;
      top : 0px;
      margin: 0 ;
      background:red;
      padding:0 0 0 0 ;
      height : 100px;
}

.container1{

      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow:hidden;
      display:none;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:flex-end;
      opacity: 0.9;

}
```

```html
<div class="container1" id="container1" >
  <form  method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="mySubmit() " style="">

      <div class = "login-box" id="login_box" style=" right:-570px;">

      </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- Button for performing animation -->
<button onclick="call_slider()" >Show/Hide Login Box</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code works perfectly. I am sorry for the late reply. Now only I tested it . Thank you once again